# How can we access a user's K8s cluster using kubectl commands via an Electron app?

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, security, npm, electron-packager

We're building a simple app that scans a user's K8s cluster via <kubectl get all -o json> then compares that data against a json file detailing all K8s API deprecations and replacements from KubePug.

**What We Have:**

- A ‘test’ user react app spun up into a K8s cluster
- A JS file that (shown below):

  - Uses Node’s ‘child_process’ to run the <kubectl get all -o json> in the terminal
  - Parse the response JSON and grab the necessary object data from the cluster (apiVersion, kind, name, namespace, etc.)

**Desired User Experience:**

1. Navigate to workdir
2. Open our app just like you would vsCode <code .>
3. GUI automatically opens that indicates the version/deprecation status of all active APIs in your cluster + other information, links, dependency trees, etc.

**Technical Flow:**

1. User navigates to application workdir
2. User executes <kdt .> in their workdir (kdt being our app name)
3. Our app starts running
4. Our app grabs the users workdir where they executed <kdt .>
5. Our app uses the code we already have to execute the <kubectl get all -o json> command inside of the user’s workdir
6. Our app performs business logic on the data
7. Our app renders data either in a localhost or desktop app GUI

**Current Roadblock:**
It’s apparent that this needs to be either an Electron app or an NPM package that a client runs locally. The NPM package approach seems light-weight and more developer-friendly. The Electron approach seems more feasible given our existing skill set but less developer-friendly.

Any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

P.S. Our React app is spun up into a K8s cluster running 3 client pods, 3 server pods, 1 worker pod, 1 postgres pod, and 1 redis pod through ingress-nginx.

Our JS file works, we just need to be able to run this in a client's terminal now.

```
const childProcess = require('child_process');

async function sh(cmd_to_execute) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        childProcess.exec(cmd_to_execute, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                const data = JSON.parse(stdout);
                const objects = data.items;
                objects.forEach((object) => {
                    console.log('****************************************')
                    console.log("Name: ", object.metadata.name);
                    console.log("Kind: ", object.kind);
                    console.log("apiVersion: ", object.apiVersion);
                })
                resolve({ stdout, stderr });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Kubectl is only a cli client that connects to the k8s api. 
In fact you only need the api to fetch your data. On top of that, if you assign privileges to a new ServiceAccount to fetch all info from k8s you can configure the pod to use the ServiceAccount. K8s will mount secrets in your pod which you can use to query the k8s api. If you use any k8s client library for nodejs it should work out of the box. 
I’m on my phone now, but if you google RBAC nodejs k8s client, you’ll probably find some good resources.